# Is there a limit to pd.to_gbq() loading to bigquery() from pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a dataframe that has about 4 million rows and 18 columns. I am trying to push to a Google Big Query Table using **pd.to_gbq().**

What I see as the end result in Google BigQuery is 2.29 million rows..

I think this may be related to the streaming buffer.. but shouldn't the details of what is loaded be accurate?

I have already checked the pandas documentation with regards to loading to Google Big query and I see no limits posted there.

Here are some test results:
[image]

Here is the code and the shape of the dataframe when I load it:
[image]

Can anyone confirm whether or not this is due to the streaming buffer? And that the actual size will be updated? Or is this an issue with pd.to_gbq() itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One limitation that I found is,
In the following code I am writing a dataframe to Bigquery. If the option `if_exists` is set to `append` the `to_gbq` function should append the result to the table if the table exist else it creates a table.
So, in the second case where it creates a new table I couldn't find a way to set the partition column.

```
results.to_gbq(f'{BQ_DATASET_NAME}.{table}',
                           PROJECT_ID,
                           chunksize=None,
                           if_exists='append',
                           table_schema=schema,
                           )
```